# Edit date when modifying in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have a date input to register dates on a form. Dates are recorded and displayed correctly. The problem comes when I want to edit the saved date, I need to show me the saved date in order to make changes.

This is my code for the date input :

```
<p>
  <label>Fecha:</label>
  <p type="Fecha:">
    <input type="date" name="fecha" step="1" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" autocomplete="off" required value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>" />
    <?php echo form_error("fecha","<span class='help-block'>","</span>") ?> 
  </p>
</p>
```

Comment: you need to show saved date when edit as `<?php echo $fecha ?>`

Comment: You have two `value` attributes and since you are only passing one argument to `date` it'll show the current date.

Comment: Try this ```<p>
 <label>Fecha:</label> 
 <p type="Fecha:">
  <input 
   type="date" 
   name="fecha" 
   step="1" 
   autocomplete="off" 
   required 
   value="<?php echo set_value('fecha', !empty($fecha) ? $fecha : date('Y-m-d')); ?>" />
  <?php echo form_error("fecha","<span class='help-block'>","</span>") ?>
 </p>
</p>```

Answer (score 0):

You are using double value attributes in the input. Please remove one and put values in the condition.

```
<p><label>Fecha:</label> <p type="Fecha:"><input type="date" name="fecha" step="1" value="<?php if(!empty($fecha)){ echo $fecha; } else { echo date("Y-m-d"); } ?>" autocomplete="off" required  /><?php echo form_error("fecha","<span class='help-block'>","</span>") ?> </p></p>
```